# How To make user see different view based on work location

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want create Condition if Code Work Location equals "Kelanis" user cannot choose past 5 days, but if work location not equals "kelanis" the user doesnt have this restriction.

```
TextBox dt = (TextBox)f.Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox1");
dt.Text = string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
CalendarExtender c1 = (CalendarExtender)f.Controls[0].FindControl("CalenderExtender1");
```

This is my problem. I want to make condition

```
c1.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day - 4); // I want this Code execute when Work Location  equal "kelanis". 
c1.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);  // execute when work location not equal "kelanis"



c1.EndDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day); // future date has been disable
```

This is picture MySQL database you can see:

[image]

My Update Make Condition like this but not reponded

CalendarExtender cal1 = (CalendarExtender)FormView1.Controls[0].FindControl("CalendarExtender1");

```
    TextBox dt = (TextBox)FormView1.Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox1");
    dt.Text = string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy}", DateTime.Now);




    if (loc.SelectedText.ToLower() == "kelanis")
    {
        cal1.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day - 4);
        cal1.EndDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);

        pan_risklvl.Visible = true;
        //ddl_risk.InitControl();
        txb_due.Enabled = false;
        lb_call_due.Enabled = false;
        cal1.Enabled = false;
        ddl_risklvl1_SelectedChanged(ddl_risk, EventArgs.Empty);

    }
    else
    {
        cal1.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
        cal1.EndDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);

        pan_risklvl.Visible = false;
        txb_due.Enabled = true;
        lb_call_due.Enabled = true;
        cal1.Enabled = true;


    }
```

Comment: use if condition

Comment: oke sir i will do, but still not respond ?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: is Code Work Location a parameter?

Comment: Sql server sir, yes Work_Location a parameter